# Horizontal spaces between subscript and regular text HTML

Tags: html, css, spacing, subscript

I am very new to using HTML and CSS. In the website I've designed mostly through copying/pasting code, I have a bunch of images with text displayed over top when your mouse hovers over them. This includes a lot of CSS which I think may be interfering with the subscript in my molecular formulas, but I'm not sure why or where?
[subscript in lower line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5jQB.png)
My first issue was that the sub tag caused the subscript to be put onto a lower line and covered by other letters. Which I fixed by adding in:

```
<style>
.textwithblurredbg sub{
vertical-align: baseline; 
font-size: 60%;
position: relative;
left:-4 em;
}

sup {
top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
bottom: -0.25em;
}
```

However, now there are huge spaces between the numbers and letters of my molecular formula. Any solutions for how to fix this would be greatly appreciated (please keep the language as simple as possible). Thank you in advance!!
[subscript numbers not attached to previous text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMePo.png)

Here's my CSS code that might be interfering:

```
<style>
.textwithblurredbg{
width:300px;
height:200;
display: inline-block;
margin:8px;
position:relative;
} 

.textwithblurredbg img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius:10px;
transition:.3s;
}

.textwithblurredbg:hover img{
filter:blur(2px) brightness(60%);
box-shadow:0 0 16px #A0C1D5;
}

.textwithblurredbg :not(img){
position:absolute;
top:10%;
z-index:1;
color: #fff;
font-family:Arial;
text-align:left;
line-height:25px;
margin:10px;
width:95%;
opacity:0;
transition;.3s;
letter-spacing:default;
}

.textwithblurredbg h3{
top:2.5%;
font-family:Arial;
text-align:center;
}


.textwithblurredbg:hover :not(img){
opacity:1;
}
```

and how I use the sub tag:

```
<div class="textwithblurredbg">
<img src="https://groups.chem.ubc.ca/chem_stockroom/images/Acetic Acid 2.0M.jpg">
<h3>Acetic Acid Solution 2.0M</h3>
<h5>Molecular Formula: C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>4</sub>O<sub>2</sub> or CH3COOH<br><br>Formula Weight: 60.05 g/mol<br>Appearance: Colourless, clear liquid<br><br>Safety: Can cause burns/blisters if comes into contact with skin.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

**All this mess was solved by making a `div` with an `id='wrapper'` and then putting inside all your text elements.** If you put these text elements outside of the wrapper they will be placed one over the other thus creating a mess you were describing. Also, subscript doesn't work.

So, set `position: relative;` to the `textwithblurredbg`, set `position: absolute;` to the `wrapper` and then put all your text elements inside the `wrapper`. Consequently:

- your text elements are now positioned one after the other (not one over the other) and
- subscript now works.

Also, I simplified your CSS a little bit.

```css
.textwithblurredbg {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 8px;
}

.textwithblurredbg img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.textwithblurredbg:hover img {
  filter: blur(2px) brightness(60%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px #A0C1D5;
}

.textwithblurredbg:hover #wrapper {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class='textwithblurredbg'>
    <img src='https://groups.chem.ubc.ca/chem_stockroom/images/Acetic Acid 2.0M.jpg'>
    <div id='wrapper'>
      <h3>Acetic Acid Solution 2.0M</h3>
      <h5>Molecular Formula: C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>4</sub>O<sub>2</sub> or CH<sub>3</sub>COOH</h5>
      <h5>Formula Weight: 60.05 g/mol<br>Appearance: Colourless, clear liquid<br><br>Safety: Can cause burns/blisters if comes into contact with skin.</h5>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help this solved my problem perfectly!